# Create html table by fetching data from database

Tags: php, html

I want to display values in a html table by fetching data from database, in each row of a table i want to show 4 columns
I want to display it like this => http://buyitnaija.com/index.php but it is actually displaying http://buyitnaija.com/index1.php

so far I have done this :

```
$category = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category LIMIT 0, 4");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($category))
{
$cat_name = $row['Category'];?>
<table class="white" width="60%" align="center">
<tr>
<td style="font-size:18px; color:#FFFFFF">
<a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>?cat=<?echo $cat_name;?>"><? echo $cat_name;?></a>
</td>
<?}?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).